# WordPress PHP, Не добавляется ссылка <a > вокруг div

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Отмеченная ссылка не работает на весь блок, вместо этого внутри блока она повторяется несколько раз, как это исправить.

````
global $post;
$query_args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'showposts' => $num, 'order_by' => $sort, 'order' => $order, 'paged' => $paged);
if( $cat ) $query_args['category_name'] = $cat;
$query = new WP_Query($query_args); ?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()): ?>

<!-- Blog Page Section -->
<section class="blog-page-section blog-classic">
    <div class="auto-container">
        <?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
        global $post;
        $posts_meta = _WSH()->get_meta();
        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_id(), 'category', array("fields" => "names")); ?>
        <!-- News Block Three -->
        
        <div class="news-block-three">
            
            <div class="inner-box">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <!-- Content Column -->
                    <div class="content-column col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 wow fadeInLeft">    
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_id())); ?>"> -- эта ссылка не обрабатывает весь блок
                        <div class="inner-column">
                            <div class="content">
                                
                                <?php if ($_GET['page_id'] == '536') {?>
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <? } else {?>
                                    <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_id())); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <? } ?>
                                
                                <ul class="post-meta">
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_id())); ?>">
                                    <li><?php echo implode( ', ', (array)$term_list ); ?></li>
                                    </a>
                                </ul>
                                
                                <?php if ($_GET['page_id'] == '536') {
                                    
                                } else {?>
                                
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_id())); ?>" class="read-more"><?php esc_html_e('Докладніше', 'intenax'); ?>
                                        <span class="arrow flaticon-next-5"></span>
                                    </a>

                                <? } ?>
                                    
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        </a>-- ее конец
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Image Column -->
                    <div class="image-column col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 wow fadeInRight">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_id())); ?>">
                        <div class="inner-column">
                            <div class="image">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('intenax_750x520'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                
        </div>
            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
<?php kama_pagenavi($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $args = array(), $wp_query = $query); // пагинация, функция нах-ся в function.php ?>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End Blog Page Section -->

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>```
````

Comment: Идите учите верстку) это не вордпресс виноват)

Answer (score 0):

Спецификация запрещает вкладывать одну ссылку в другую. Если так сделать, то браузер вас не поймёт и, как только встретит открывающий тег вложенной ссылки, закроет родительскую ссылку перед собой.

Answer (score 0):

По спецификации HTML запрещено вкладывать строчные `display: inline;` элементы в блочные `display: block;`, поэтому так и происходит

Должно быть так:

```
<div class="text-style">
    <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

Или

```
<div class="text-style">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="inner-text-style">Text</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Это же касается и ваших списков `<a>` должен быть внутри `<li>`:

```
<ul class="text-style">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

То, что WordPress научили думать за вас, не говорит о том, что он кривой и в нем баги. Просто нужно Читать, учить и развиваться